# Is it possible to start a VM inside a WorkerRole?

Tags: azure

I have a little OS that I'd like to start and use in Azure and thought about running a VM inside a WorkerRole. I know it is possible to use Azure VM roles for that but my exercise is to run it from inside a Worker/WebRole. Is that possible?

I tried installing VirtualBox and running that in a WorkerRole but when running the OS my WorkerRole just reboots.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a VM inside a VM in Azure. A Worker Role (or *instances* of a Worker Role) are already Windows Server 2008 / 2012 VMs. As @Robert pointed out, Azure has support for Virtual Machines, whether Linux or Windows, where you have complete control of its contents.

Regarding **I have a little OS that I'd like to start**: You can only run supported OS's that are listed in the Virtual Machine gallery: Ubuntu, CentOS, Windows Server, SUSE currently. More info on Linux VMs [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/), Windows Server [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the VM gallery limitation.

Comment: Or use an image from the VM Depot: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2013/01/10/using-the-vm-depot.aspx

Comment: Right, but... the images in VM Depot are still configured with one of the supported Linux distros found in the VM gallery. There's no ability to upload a different OS image there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not technically supported by Microsoft and is not recommended (even if you could easily) since Azure is constantly taking down and bringing back up your Web/Worker role instances in a deployment.

This means that any manual changes made to your WorkerRole will be undone any time Azure bounces your deployment (i.e. data center issues, migrations, etc.)  This happens much more often than you'd think.

You should check out Azure's [VM support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/) which may have what you need.

Comment: Understand, many thanks. If SO supported two answers, I'd check yours as well :)